# simple mathematical calculation in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, math, stat

I have read many help topics here but never found the answer on my specific question or issue.

I have this bash code in red hat 7 (not that it matters but .. )

```
    if [[ $(stat -c %s) -gt 1024 ]];
    then
    echo "            $(scale=1;stat -c %s log.txt / 1024) KiloBytes"
    else
    echo "            $(stat -c %s log.txt) Bytes"
    fi
```

and it throws this error:

`stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
            0 Bytes`

With this tiny check i want to see if the log.txt is bigger than 1024 bytes, if its true, divide total byte size by 1024 and echo the output as XXXX KiloBytes. But what am I missing. Shellcheck.com says everything is okay...

Can anyone help me out on this matter?

Comment: What are you trying to `stat`?  You aren't telling it to stat anything, so it's complaining about that.  Did you mean `$(stat -c %s log.txt)`?

Comment: yes i meant `$(stat -c %s log.txt) ` thank you

Comment: BTW, instead of executing `stat` again, you probably just want to store the result in a variable, then test and pretty-print the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a filename.  You probably want a

```
if [[ $(stat -c %s log.txt) -gt 1024 ]];
#            look: ^^^^^^^
```

to be your first line. If you do as instructed and type `stat --help`, it will show you that the correct usage is

```
Usage: stat [OPTION]... FILE...
Display file or file system status.
```

`-c %s` is OPTIONS and you don't have any file specified in the first line.

Comment: I cant believe i did oversee that, im sorry. Thank you for your guidance and help. it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a call to `bc`, which is a program used for floating-point arithmetic. `scale=1` is usually part of the input to `bc`:

```
# No
echo "            $(scale=1;stat -c %s log.txt / 1024) KiloBytes"
# Yes - broken down into steps for easy reading
size=$(stat -c %s log.txt)
result=$(echo "scale=1; $size / 1024" | bc)
echo "            $result KiloBytes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd be interested in cutting down the size of your script:

```
stat -c %s log.txt | awk '{ print ($0 > 1024 ? $0 / 1024 " Kilobytes" : $0 " bytes") }'
```

Parse the output of `stat` using awk and print either bytes or Kilobytes, depending on the size.